# Query on $.get(), Express and JSON in NodeJS application

Tags: jquery, json, node.js, express

In the NodeJS application using Express, I use the below query to send data from client to server

```
$('#frmadd').on('submit',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    form_elements = $('#frmadd').serializeArray();
    $.get('/add_details',{input: form_elements})
    .done(function(data){
      //SOME STATEMENTS
  },'json');
```

And I use `bodyParser` on the server side and I've appended `'json'` at the end of the above code. I've read that it coverts the data stream into JSON format and sends it to the server.

And I also have read that EXPRESS actually takes care of the JSON conversions i.e., stringifies the object when sent from client to server and auto parses when sent from server to client. So in that case why do we need to attach `'json'` in the code ? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Also in the above code, with or without adding the `'json'` is not making any difference. I can happily able to access the data object at server side. So what is the extra use provided by attaching the `'json'`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `'json'` argument you show in your code is the second parameter to `.done()` which is not used.

Comment: Hi, so express taking care of the JSON conversions...?? We do not need to explicitly specify before sending data to server from client.??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no JSON that I'm aware of in your request.  The object you are passing to `$.get(url, dataObject)` is put into the query string as `prop=val` pairs.  The Express `body-parser` module, parses the query string for you and puts the results into `req.query` for you.

The data in the query string is query string encoded by jQuery and then decoded and parsed by the body-parser module in Express.

If you are doing a POST, you can then decide whether you want the data to be encoded as JSON or form encoded, but for GET requests data goes in the query string which is always URL encoded.

FYI, the `'json'` argument you show in your code is showing as a 2nd argument to `.done()` which is not used and thus is ignored.

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation. Also Is my above statement correct ? - Express takes care of JSON conversions : Auto stringifies data when sent from server to client and auto parses when data sent from client to server ?

Comment: @METALHEAD - There are some cases where some Express middleware will automatically parse JSON for you, but that isn't what is happening here.  Likewise, there are some cases where jQuery will convert to JSON for you and send JSON if that is specified.  But, again that is not what is happening here.

Answer (score 1):

IT is used to set Content type of data